# Puppet compare ini file between server and agent

Tags: puppet

its possible to compare ini file before copy to agent ?
for example I have sys.ini file  on different agents:

```
Agent-1:
sys.ini
---ip:x.x.x.1

Agent-2:
sys.ini
---ip:x.x.x.2
```

Now I want add new line to the sys.ini on the Puppet Server like:

```
> sys.ini
> ---ip:x.x.x.x
> ---name:x.x.x.x
```

I want to add only the NAME to the sys.ini on agent-1 and 2, is that possible ?
Not to override the whole sys.ini on agents.

thanks in advance

Regards,
Andy

Comment: Files are already automatically compared before copying to the agent, and that comparison does not help you with the functionality you are looking for. Is there a reason you want to only manage one line instead of the file? `file_line` from `stdlib` does that, but I see no reason in your question for not managing the entire file.

Comment: thanks for your amswer @Matt Schuchard,  yes I have a reason, I have more than 40 Agents and all keys in sys.ini  have different values, so I want compare only the keys if they are available in the sys.ini dont add it else add the new key to the file with "default"  value. Yes I use already file_line in another situations :-)

Comment: Ok, based on the information provided both managing the entire file with `file` and managing lines with `file_line` will do that for you. One of us could write up an answer for you given a more specific question with what you have tried thus far and the results.

Comment: thanks again for your answer @MattSchuchard I'll start to combine file with file_line and this is a good start, and after that I'll post the solution or further questions when I have... Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to ensure a line exists within a file without replacing or managing the entire contents of the file.

You can do this with the `file_line` resource from the puppetlabs/stdlib module. https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#file_line

```
file_line { 'name_line':
  path => 'sys.ini',
  line => '---name:whatever',
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Mike Marseglia,  its also possible if the line is not exist to add it to the sys.ini ?

Comment: Hi @Andy.  `file_line` will add the line to the end of the file if it doesn't exist.